# Why do college calculus books define limits on open intervals?

Tags: calculus, limits, math-history

In every undergraduate level Calculus book I've seen (Stewart, Thomas, Larson/Edwards, etc.), single-variable limits are defined to exist on open intervals which forbids finding limits at endpoints of intervals. Limits at endpoints require a "one-sided limit" in these books. Curiously, all of these same books allow multivariable limits to exist on not-necessarily-open sets, allowing limits to exist at boundary points (so their multivariable definition does not restrict naturally to their single variable definition).

There are several threads on this site that discuss taking limits at endpoints, often resolving with "It depends on how you define a limit."

My question is: Why do undergraduate texts require open intervals for limits? Or, perhaps more generally, why do some prefer a definition that requires an open interval? Is there a historical perspective that motivates this?

Comment: I don't see any good reason for doing that.

Comment: Could you provide a quote? I have never seen such thing. Many people do define **differentiability** on open sets out of convenience.

Comment: @Daniel Things get hairy when you want to discuss the continuity of the square root function at 0 but also don't want to worry about restricting $x$ to the domain of the function in a first Calculus class.

Comment: @MarkS. I don't understand that. When one is considering continuity of a function, one has to restrict to the domain of that function. $\sqrt{\text{my left sock}}$ just doesn't make sense.

Comment: I feel like this is a better question for the MathEd StackExchange. I cannot think of any good _mathematical_ reason for that definition, but I can see why _pedagogically_ this emphasis can be useful as a starting point. (Requiring the limit to mean two-sided limits allows one to immediately demonstrate functions for which the left and right limits don't agree, thereby getting easy examples of discontinuous functions. Functions for which the one-sided limit do not exist are a bit harder to write down/draw/explain.)

Comment: @user251257 Stewart's (by far the best-selling Calc text in the U.S.) definition begins with "Let f be a function defined on some open interval that contains the number a ..."    Once we establish limits can occur on closed intervals, it seems a short jump to allow derivatives, too. Why not find f'(5) when f(x) = x^2 on [2,5]? The limit exists when one defines the limit to be ok on closed intervals.

Comment: @WillieWong There indeed may be a pedagogical reason. I put my question here as I thought there may be a _historical_ reason. (I'm doubtful of the pedagogical reasoning, though: look closely at most calc texts and this open-interval restriction gets abused often, making texts inconsistent.)

Comment: @GregH you cut off the interesting part of your quote. Theory about continuous function on **intervals** is much stronger than on arbitrary set. Just think about the intermediate value theorem. But there is no particular reason for **open** intervals beside convenience.

Comment: @user251257 The rest of the quote is boilerplate stuff, IMO. It says "the limit of f as x approaches a is L if for every number epsilon >0 there is a number delta > 0 such that if 0<|x-a|<delta, then |f(x) - L| < epsilon." I see restricting to *interval* for pedagogical reasons. The crux of my question is "Why *open* intervals?"

Comment: @GregH for few proofs you need two-sided limits and then make some small adaption to one-sided limits. Such technical details doesn't offer more insight. Perhaps some authors think such details might confuse students. Again, I haven't seen that in any books. So I am kind of wild guessing...

Answer (score 1):

Assume that a set $\Omega\subset{\mathbb R}^n$, a function $f:\>\Omega\to{\mathbb R}$, and a point $\xi\in{\mathbb R}^n$ are given. It may be that $f$ a priori is defined on some larger set $\Omega'\supset\Omega$, but that for some special reasons we momentarily consider $f(x)$ only for points  $x\in \Omega$.

If $\xi\notin\overline{\Omega}$, i.e., if there is an $\epsilon_0>0$ such that $|\xi-x|\geq\epsilon_0$ for all $x\in\Omega$, then it makes no sense to consider the limit $\lim_{x\to\xi} f(x)$.

If, however $\xi\in\overline{\Omega}$, then there are are points $x\in\Omega$ arbitrarily near $\xi$, and it makes sense to consider $\lim_{x\to\xi} f(x)$. By definition,
$$\lim_{x\to\xi}f(x)=L\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad\ldots$$
where the $\ldots$ express that for any $\epsilon>0$ there has to be a $\delta>0$ such that
$$x\in\Omega\quad\wedge\quad0<|x-\xi|<\delta\qquad\Rightarrow\quad |f(x)-L|<\epsilon\ .$$
This is the general definition of limit, and it encompasses one-sided limits, limits at boundary points, etc., as well. (Only $\xi=\pm\infty$ is not covered.) The limit defined in "calculus books" may be restricted to more special situations, but it must not differ from the general idea presented here.

Comment: I'm fine with this definition. You make no restrictions on your set omega. In your definition, let n=1. It makes sense, pedagogically, to restrict sets to in R to intervals and build (later) from there. But why *open* intervals? My curiosity is why do most (perhaps, American) calc books do that?

Comment: This answers "What is the general definition of limit?", which is a question different from OP's.